# Laravel: How to handle rate limit using Redis/database queue?

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, mailtrap

How can I set up Laravel queues using database/Redis connection so that job does not fail for the Mailtrap rate limit of *five emails per 10 secs*? For example, I tried to execute six jobs with two workers using Redis.
But the 6th job failed with the error below in failed jobs table.

> Too many emails per second.

```
Redis::throttle('key')->allow(5)->every(10)->then(function () {
    $email = new WelcomeEmail();
    Mail::to('info@test.com')->send($email);
}, function () {
    return $this->release(7);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Karl Hill for Question improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Mailtrap only allows 5 mails per 10 seconds for free and individual. You can check their pricing page. If you buy their **team** subscription then it will allow you to send 25 mails per 10 seconds BUT it will cost you 24.99 USD

Comment: Thanks @gguney, but i was trying a work around by delaying.

Comment: Can you use "delay" function I did not get yout point exactly sorry my bad :(

Comment: Redis::throttle('keydock')->block(15)->allow(5)->every(15) seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

We have two queues, q1(waiting) and q2(processing). The publisher push tasks on q1, the worker then pops a task off of q1 and push it into q2. After processing  by worker  is completed, the task is removed from q2.
if q2 task crashed, failed or takes too long to completed the task. The task is then transferred to q1 to be picked again by worker

[Example with database: Processing job Queue with two worker for eleven jobs with default timeout of 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okHdN.png)

So this works fine with two workers only, for four workers it will fail due to early completion.
we need to increase no of tries, as 3 tries exhausted within current 10 sec limit.